# How do we get a function that returns a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, function

So I'm new to Python and heres my code:

```
def sum_is_less_than(numeric_value, list_of_numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in list_of_numbers:
        total = total + number
        if total > numeric_value:
            break
        print(total)

numeric_value = 100
list_of_numbers = [2, 3, 45, 33, 20, 14, 5]

sum_is_less_than(numeric_value, list_of_numbers)
```

So what this code is doing, it's adding the values of the list as long as it's under the given numeric value. I want the code to output the first N elements in the list whose sum is less than the given numeric value.

For example: [1,2,3,4,5,6] and given numeric value is 10

I want the code to output [1,2,3] as adding 4 would make the sum greater or equal to the given numerical value.

Comment: Do you want your function to return a list or print it?

Comment: what is the exact issue here?

Comment: "How do we get a function that returns a list in Python?" Well, do you know how to write code that creates a list? Do you know how to write code that puts things into a list? Do you know what `return` means in Python code, and what it has to do with returning a value? If you put those ideas together, can you see how to solve the problem? "I want the code to output [1,2,3] as adding 4 would make the sum greater or equal to the given numerical value." Oh, so it's a little more complicated. Can you think of a logical process that tells you which numbers to put into the list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and then make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Start by (I am dead serious) taking out a real pen or pencil and piece of paper, and writing out, in English, in full words - with pictures and diagrams, if they help you understand - the process that you want to use in order to solve the problem. Think carefully about what pieces of information you need to keep track of, and what steps need to be repeated, and how to decide to stop the process.

Comment: ❤️ the pen and pencil advice, I always have one around ;)

Comment: I want the function to print the list of the list of the first n numbers whose sum is less than the given numerical value.  The code I wrote is only adding up the items in the list and stopping when the next item on the list will make the sum greater than the given numerical value.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, use `out = []` and `out.append(...)` in your code. Alternative, use a counter to keep track of the index that you add.

Comment: Okay, so what things do you need to do in order to get the result you want? You already have the code to find the numbers that you want and stop at the appropriate time, correct? So, the remaining part is actually putting things in the list, right? If you don't know how to do that, consider starting by using a search engine (even the [simplest queries imaginable](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+make+a+list) will give you useful results for something like this), or following a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to get a list out of your function you need to actually return something. Here, `output` starts as an empty list and gets appended with values from yout original list `list_of_numbers`, until the sum is higher then the passed numeric value.

```
def sum_is_less_than(numeric_value, list_of_numbers):
        total = 0
        output = []
        for number in list_of_numbers:
            total = total + number
            output.append(number) 
            if total > numeric_value:
                return output
        return output
```

A use case would be:

```
value = 10
list_of_numbers = [3,4,5,6]
list_sum_smaller_then_value = sum_is_less_than(numeric_value, list_of_numbers)
```

Comment: Please do not spoon-feed code for questions that do not come even close to meeting minimum requirements. Even where writing code is appropriate, an explanation is expected. Here, however, OP has shown no initiative and *does not have a specific question*.

Comment: I placed the append after the if statement, and that seemed to have worked. Your time is appreciated, thank you. I just want people to know that if I’m posting on stacked overflow I have tried for at least 3 hours on my own and if I’m still not able to figure something out, stacked is my last resort. I really appreciate everyone’s time here!

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. If you place `output.append(number)` after the if-statement, you won't get the lust number that lead to exiting the function. I guess this depends on your task!

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_is_less_than(numeric_value, list_of_numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in list_of_numbers:
        total += number
        if total < numeric_value:
            print(number)
        else:
            break

numeric_value = 10
list_of_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

sum_is_less_than(numeric_value, list_of_numbers)
```

Comment: Please do not spoon-feed code for questions that do not come even close to meeting minimum requirements. Even where writing code is appropriate, an explanation is expected. Here, however, OP has shown no initiative and *does not have a specific question*.

Comment: It certainly does. First off, the site does not require me to justify downvotes in the first place. Second, questions that don't meet site standards are supposed to be closed and deleted, and not answered. Upvoted answers interfere with the deletion process. If this bothers you, please take the issue to https://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way (short, efficient and pythonic). The first expression is a [generator](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/generator-comprehension-in-python), meaning that it does not calculate values unnecessarily.

```py
def sum_is_less_then(numeric_value, list_of_numbers: list):
    res = (sum(list_of_numbers[:idx]) for idx, _ in enumerate(list_of_numbers))
    return [x for x in res if x < numeric_value]

print (sum_is_less_then(30, [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,3,3,6]))
# result: [0, 1, 3, 7, 12, 18, 25]
```